# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to parse XML

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

This problem really has me scratching my head.

I have a chat application that parses xml from the server. It is successful parsing the message text, msg id, but I am getting a nullpointerException for the UserID but I am pulling it from the same location. Please help

```
// Get messages
            NodeList messageList = documentElement.getElementsByTagName("MESSAGE");
            ret.messages = new ChatStruct[messageList.getLength()];
            Log.v("response","Message Length " + messageList.getLength());
            for (int i = 0; i < messageList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element messageNode = (Element) messageList.item(i);
                ret.messages[i] = new ChatStruct();
                // Get messageId
                try {
                    Element messageIdNode = (Element) messageNode.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0);
                    String messageId = messageIdNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                     System.out.println("messageId = " + messageId);
                    ret.messages[i].id = Long.parseLong(messageId);
                    //Log.v("Util","Message ID " + Long.parseLong(messageId));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ret.messages[i].id = 0l;
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Get text
                try {
                    Element textNode = (Element) messageNode.getElementsByTagName("TEXT").item(0);
                    String text = textNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    System.out.println("text = " + text);
                    ret.messages[i].textMessage = text.trim();
                    //Log.v("Util","Message text " + text.trim());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ret.messages[i].textMessage = "";
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Get userId
                try {
                    //ret.messages[i].userId = 1;
                    //Log.v("Util @ userID node","userID should be 1");
                    Element userIdNode = (Element) messageNode.getElementsByTagName("USERID").item(0);
                    Log.i("Util @ userID node","userIdNode set");

                    String userId = userIdNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    //String userId = "1";  
                    Log.i("Util @ userID node","userId String set");
                    System.out.println("userId = " + userId);
                    ret.messages[i].userId = Long.parseLong(userId);
                    //ret.messages[i].userId = 1;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Util @ userID node", "there was an error " + e);
                    ret.messages[i].userId = 0l;
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I can hard code the string and it works but other than that the error occurs at

```
String userId = userIdNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

It makes it up to commented line of code confirming the userIDNode is set

I can't figure out why userID is not coming in from the server here is the XML:

```
<MESSAGE>
<ID><?php echo $row_shouts['msgid']; ?></ID>
<USERID><?php echo $row_shouts['userid']; ?></USERID>
<GENDER><?php echo $row_shouts['gender']; ?></GENDER>
<ONLINE><?php echo $row_shouts['account_status'];?></ONLINE>
<TDATE><?php echo datee("h:i:s M, d Y", strtotime($row_shouts['date'])); ?></TDATE>
<ICONID><?php echo $iconid; ?></ICONID>
<PIC><?php echo $PIC; ?></PIC>
<MSGPIC><?php echo $row_shouts['media']; ?></MSGPIC>
<PICDATE><?php echo strtotime($row_shouts['picdate']); ?></PICDATE>
<ALIAS><![CDATA[<?php echo $row_shouts['nickname'];?>]]></ALIAS>
<TEXT><![CDATA[<?php echo $mesg;?>]]></TEXT>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: it seems nothing problem in your parsing codes..

i think response(or source) XML might have a problem.. 
why don't you check full source of XML before parsing?

Comment: Can you tell me how I would do this?

Comment: First try hardcoding the userid in the xml like <USERID>1</USERID> and make sure the problem isn't on the server side.

Comment: i think userid value might be null value..
so response XML contain string like this
<USERID></USERID>
in this case.. USERID Element have no childElement.. so.. it occur NullPointerException..

just my guessing..

Comment: it works if I hard code it

Answer (score 0):

Did you check with the DTD file for the supplied Xml, May be USERID is not clearly defined there.
[please share the error logs]

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. Where is the DTD file? in Logcat I can only see the error due to: Log.v("Util @ userID node", "there was an error " + e); that is when it tells me java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: FYI,The path for DTD is defined in your XML file in its header for e.g.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">` @TWeeKeD

Answer (score -1):

What's the execption say if you print the stack trace? It might be because the user id isn't a long and you're trying to parse it. I don't see any errors in the retrieval of the user id.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: 01-14 13:01:50.974: V/Util @ userID node(7738): there was an error java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No not your error code in the catch, print out the stack trace, uncomment out this line: 
                    // e.printStackTrace();

Comment: 01-14 15:39:00.179: W/System.err(1076): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 15:39:00.179: W/System.err(1076):  at com.peekatucorp.peekatu.misc.Util.getNewMessages(Util.java:975)

Comment: line 975 is: String userId = userIdNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

Comment: This should really be a comment. Don't ask questions in your answers.